# comparing against undefined

Tags: javascript

Is it unsafe to compare a variable against undefined?

```
if(foo == undefined)
```

vs

```
if(foo == 'undefined')
```

Is the first example sufficient? Or should it be something like

```
if('undefined' in window){
     //compare against undefined
} else {
    //compare against 'undefined'
}
```

since `undefined` exists on the `window` object? Will it exist in all browsers? Or should I simply compare to `== 'undefined'`? I've found some similar questions on SO, but no answers regarding the existance of the undefined property on the window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting  mixed up between `foo == undefined` and `typeof foo == "undefined"`.

Both will yield the same result *unless* the variable `undefined` has been set to something else in the current scope. In this case, `foo == undefined` will compare against that, where-as `typeof foo == "undefined"` will still resolve correctly.

```
var undefined = 4;
var reallyUndefined;

reallyUndefined == undefined; // false
typeof reallyUndefined == undefined; // true
```

Whether it's a real world scenario that `undefined` will ever be set to something else is debatable, and I'd question the validity of the library/ code that does that... Because of this however, it's deemed good practise to always use `typeof foo === "undefined"`.

I'd also be wary about using `foo == undefined` against `foo === undefined` (note the triple equals, which does not use type-coercian, compared to `==` which does).

Using `==`, you run the risk of things like `null == undefined; // true`, where-as `null === undefined; // false`. This is a good example of why you should **always** use `===`.

---

**tl;dr**: `typeof foo === "undefined";`

Comment: Your right about my mixup :) However, i dont see why typeof returns the type string and not undefined. Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: @Johan: Because `typeof` does just that; always returns a string. For example `typeof "foo" === "string`, `typeof 5 === "number"`, `typeof function(){} === "function"`. For more info, you can read the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) on it.

Comment: *"I'd question the validity of the library/ code that does that..."* This sentence needs to be bold, italic and surrounded in flashing lights. ;)

Comment: Hmm ok, i guess it makes sense since javascript isnt strongly typed

Comment: @Johan: It isn't really to do with the weakness of JavaScript. Imagine `typeof` as a function which accepts *something* (function, object, string), and returns it's true type as a string (in reality `typeof` is an operator, but thinking about it in this way for a bit might cement the understanding).

Comment: Strongly typed has nothing to do with weakness of the language. If I, for example, would use typeof in c#, i would get the actual type, and not the string representation of a type.

Comment: @Johan: Eugh, sorry, I didn't mean it as a language weakness. I meant it as in weakly-typed-ness of the language :). I guess `typeof` in C# returns a System.Type, where-as in JavaScript returns it as a string... just 2 different languages doing 2 different things :).

Comment: Indeed :) Thanks again for clarifying the javascript-part for me

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) instead:

```
if (typeof foo == "undefined") {
    // ...
}
```

Note, that `typeof` returns a *string*, so you should *always* compare it with string value.

Comment: And would it ever be wrong to use `(typeof foo == undefined)`?

Comment: I think typeof returns strings.

Comment: @Johan `typeof` always returns a string.

Comment: @Johan You can do `typeof foo == undefined` when you want a guarantee of a `false` result. ;P

Comment: But as long as i dont use `===` it should still work, right? Since `undefined == 'undefined' //true` but `undefined === 'undefined' //false`. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Johan: Yes, you're wrong. ;-) `undefined` does not equal `'undefined'`.

Comment: @user1689607 Ok, mixed em up with `1 == '1'` and similar stuff :-)

Comment: @Johan: Yes, the `==` is messy. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (foo === undefined)
```

Is safe

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but the easiest I've found is this:

```
if(foo === undefined){
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have complete control of all the code and you know you won't have to worry about someone mucking about with `undefined` then it is safe to compare against it.

```
alert(window.foo === undefined);
```

On the other hand, if you want to be a bit more paranoid, you can do a typeof check which can't be affect by the outside word

```
alert(typeof window.foo == 'undefined')
```

The third option is to have your own, local, undefined variable.

```
function testme(a, undefined) {
   alert(a === undefined); // Will be false.
}

testme(10);
```